# Loop over html table and get checked checkboxes (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table with a checkbox in each row.
I want to loop over the table and see if there are any checkboxes that are checked.
The following does not work:

```
$("#save").click( function() {
    $('#mytable tr').each(function (i, row) {
        var $actualrow = $(row);
        checkbox = $actualrow.find('input:checked');
        console.log($checkbox);
});
```

This prints in the console the following:

`[prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: tr, selector: "input:checked", constructor: function, init: function…]`

per row regardless of whether any checkbox is checked.

**Update**
Same issue with:

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function (i, row) {                                                                                                 
   var $actualrow = $(row);
    $checkbox = $actualrow.find(':checkbox:checked');
    console.log($checkbox);  
});
```

Comment: Yup, a jQuery object is printed to the console, which is normal. Did you check its `length` property?

Comment: Have you tried with `$actualrow.find('input').is(':checked');`

Comment: log `$checkbox.length`. Is the length non zero?

Comment: @FredericHamidi:Length is 0

Comment: So how can I use the fact that length is 0?

Comment: @Jim, there you go. It means no checkbox was checked for that row. As for how to use it, you could write an `if` statement.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    $('#mytable').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked') //...
});
```

Let me explain you what the selector does:
`input[type="checkbox"]` means that this will match each `<input />` with type attribute `type` equals to `checkbox`
After that: `:checked` will match all checked checkboxes.

You can loop over these checkboxes with:

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    $('#mytable').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
       //this is the current checkbox
    });
});
```

Here is demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DuE8K/).

---

And here is a demo which solves exactly your problem http://jsfiddle.net/DuE8K/1/.

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    $('#mytable').find('tr').each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') &&
            row.find('textarea').val().length <= 0) {
            alert('You must fill the text area!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to get the individually.If a checkbox is checked but the textbox in the same row is not filled I want to show an alert

Comment: Ok, but how do I get the textbox in the next column of the same row to check if it is populated and if not show an alert?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/DuE8K/2/. Do you see the variables `textarea` and `checkbox`? They are referencing to the textarea and checkbox located in the current row.

Comment: Works like a charm!Is it too much to ask how could I make the coresponding row red besided the alert?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35903/discussion-between-minko-gechev-and-jim)

Comment: I am sorry!I just saw your msg

Comment: Works like charm, Is there a way to get the value of the checked checkbox using similar code?

Answer (score 2):

use `.filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)'` ie:

```
$('#mytable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
 $('#out').append(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> The following code snippet enables/disables a button depending on whether at least one checkbox on the page has been checked.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    $('#test > tbody  tr').each(function () {
        if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
            $('#btnexcellSelect').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#btnexcellSelect').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            console.log( $(this).attr('id'));
         }else{
             console.log($(this).attr('id'));
         }
     });
});
```

Here is demo in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abellopes/hkyk1yr2/18/).